# Can I run bash scripts on my Heroku account?

Tags: bash, heroku

Is it possible to run bash scripts in the new [Heroku](http://www.heroku.com/) stack? How?

Answer (score 30):

The new Celadon Cedar which was released on 5/31/2011 does seem to support running many bash scripts via 'heroku run bash'.

Examples, details and discussions can be found [here](http://www.quora.com/Heroku/How-does-Heroku-work) and [here](http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=2602728)